# How can one write the `clip-path` property using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How do I write the `clip-path` property in Tailwind CSS for element clipping? Seeking a concise example or syntax using Tailwind classes. Here is my code where I have not idea how to write `clip-path` property in Tailwind CSS.

```html
<div class="relative">
  <img src="your-image.jpg" alt="Your Image" class="absolute inset-0 w-full h-full object-cover" style="clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 100%);">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using an [arbitrary property class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties), [escaping spaces with underscores](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#handling-whitespace):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="relative w-20 h-20">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/80/80" alt="Your Image" class="absolute inset-0 w-full h-full object-cover [clip-path:polygon(0_0,100%_0,100%_80%,0_100%)]">
</div>
```